# will a nullable bit field return false when NULL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a column DBIsValid of type bit which is nullable.

I have a variable IsValid of type bool which I want to set as True if the DBIsvalid is True. Should my below line of code work fine or should I be checking for NULLs.

```
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid.Value
```

Basically will DBIsValid return false if it is NULL in DB?

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you select the value from the database. The problem is not clear. _What_ is `DBIsValid` at all?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `HasValue` property, if the value is null accessing `.Value` will throw an exception.

Another safer way to get value is using [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: Would this work  if i want to return false when Null
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid == true;

Comment: yes. default value of bool is `false`, so `GetValueOrDefault` will return `false` if the value is null. you can also specify a defalt value using other overload like : `this.DBIsValid.GetValueOrDefault(false)` but it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No, It has three states: `true`, `false` and `null`, `null` meaning no value.

If you access `this.DBIsValid.Value` when `this.DBIsValid` is `null` an exception will be thrown.

In the case you want to give the `null` value a meaning of `false`, you have to test any of the following:

```
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid ??  false; // commom pattern for a default
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid.GetValueOrDefault(); // works because false is the default value for booleans
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid.HasValue && this.DBIsValid.Value; // interprets no value as false
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's nullable, you'll receive a `null` (which is neither true nor false).

When referencing any kind of `Nullable<T>` though, you should be checking `HasValue`. Alternatively, if you have a desired value when there is a null, you can use `GetValueOrDefault`.

```
// Value coming from database
Boolean? db_IsValid = null;

// Option 1:
// Check for null
Boolean IsValid = db_IsValue.HasValue ? db_IsNull.Value : false;

// Option 2:
// Using GetValueOrDefault
Boolean IsValid = db_IsValid.GetValueOrDefault(/*optional: false*/);
// note above, without parameter, returns default(Boolean)

// Option 3:
// Syntactical sugar (producing same output as Option 1 or 2)
Boolean IsValid = IsValid ?? false;
```

Comment: Would this work  if i want to return false when Null
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid == true;

Comment: Yes. if `DBIsValid = null`, then comparing `DBIsValid == true` results in `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the null coalescing operator ?? as shown below

```
bool IsValid = this.DBIsValid ?? false
```